# Dev environment not accepting login with users that exist in local SQL database PHP/Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I recently got a new laptop and am cloning my companies repo to continue development. I've set up apache, php, apache directives, etc. Now, I get to the login page of the site (localhost) and the user credentials (which are correct from the fixtures that pre-persist into the database) are saying incorrect username/password. I realize there is a huge list of issues that could potentially cause this, but I am wondering if there is a mysql specific issue I should check for first to ensure I can login with the users from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check that you're correctly connecting to the MySQL database from the PHP code first.  You don't mention where you're getting the "incorrect username/password" error, so we can't tell if it's coming from a nice feedback message on the website or if you're looking at some kind of MySQL access log.

Comment: The database is connected successfully to the site and it's just a nice feedback message coded in the site.

Comment: If that's the case, it's hard to suggest specific troubleshooting actions without more detail into what you're seeing, since your feedback is just coming from the user interface.  I'd start with looking into the PHP and figuring out what's triggering the error message if that's all you have to go on.

Comment: Ok. I guess I am wondering where I can look specifically since my sql connect file is matching verbatim to sql credentials.